# How to access an Objective-C class method from Swift language

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my Swift app, I need to access a class method called `weibo()` as below from Objective-C

```
@interface Weibo : NSObject
+ (Weibo*)weibo;
@end
```

I have configured the bridging header and tried the following statement

```
let w = Weibo.weibo() as Weibo
```

It doesn't work.

UPDATE:
I have forked [the repo](https://github.com/JakeLin/WeiboSDK) and fixed this issue as below.

```
let w = Weibo.getWeibo() as Weibo // the method has been changed.
```

The reason why it didn't work because Swift treats `+ (Weibo*)weibo;` as a convenience constructor. Since `weibo` is same as the Class name `Weibo` although the case is different. I need to change the name to `getWeibo` to fix this issue to support Swift.

Thanks for every one contributing to this answer. Special thanks to @Anil and @David

Jake

Comment: That's a class method not a property. i.e. `Weibo.weibo()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`+ (Weibo*)weibo;` is the class method of your class `Weibo`. You could access it in swift like

```
let w:Weibo = Weibo.weibo()
```

But it gives me error when i tried(`'weibo' is unavailable: use object construction 'Weibo()'`) may be because of method name and class name are same. When i change the method name error goes

```
let w:Weibo = Weibo.getWeibo() // works: method name changed
```

Comment: It depends on what the method does.  The swift compiler is treating it as a convenience constructor, which is why you get the error message.  If that is the case, you should just use `let w = Weibo()`. If, as I suspect, it's a singleton method, you'll need to change the name of the method to someing that doesn't look like a convenience constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have forked the repo and fixed it.

Comment: @David, thanks for pointing out convenience constructor. I saw it in the WWDC video before. Thanks again.

Comment: I've a class with name "MMSDK" with a class method "+ (void)initialize;", I tried to call MMSDK.initialize() but its not working. Am I missing anything. The error that I'm getting is "Expected deceleration". What's the problem?

Comment: @Satyam Have you imported the class via `bridging header?

Comment: @Anil: Yes, bridging header is available with proper import statement.

Comment: @GarlicFries, The problem in my case is that, I'm using external "Framework". I solved the problem by placing both framework and bridging header in same folder and importing full path of the header file from the framework. Also I edited the path of the bridging header file in the "Build Settings" of Xcode. Finally I solved the problem following above method.

Comment: @Satyam `+(void)initialize` is a custom method defined by the Objective-C runtime and should never be directly invoked. The bridge may be aware of this. The `initialize` method we be called before anything else is called on that class.

Answer (score 4):

That's a class method not a property.

So you would access it like...

```
let w = Weibo.weibo()
```

... I think.

Type would be inferred but you could do it as...

```
let w:Weibo = Weibo.weibo() as Weibo
```

I believe, and it would still work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the  same problem by change code

```
+(instancetype _Nonnull)manager;
```

you should change it like this

```
@property(nonatomic, class, strong, readonly) CKKNetManager *_Nonnull manager;
```

then you can call in Swift like this

```
CKKNetManager.manager.get(kGetCompanyInfo, success: {[unowned self] (obj) in

        self.hideEmptyView()
        self.info = CKKCorpInfo.init(dictionary: obj as! [String : AnyObject])
    }) {[unowned self]  (errorString) in

        self.showEmptyView(in: self.view, with: EmptyViewType.pageLoadFailed)
    }
```

Comment: or rename like this    `code  + (instancetype _Nonnull)sharedManager; `
then call   `code CKKNetManager.shared().get(kGetCompanyInfo, success: {[unowned self] (obj) in
            
            self.hideEmptyView()
            self.info = CKKCorpInfo.init(dictionary: obj as! [String : AnyObject])
        }) {[unowned self]  (errorString) in
            
            self.showEmptyView(in: self.view, with: EmptyViewType.pageLoadFailed)
        }`

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, my Obj-c class method returned a pointer to a new class not added to my bridging header so the compiler did not make that class method accessible.

You need both the class with the class method you want to call and any class in the class method's description to be included in your bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problems as I had in the past, the reason why I could not access the function from swift is because it was missing the function declaration in the .h (header) file.
So it was only in the .m file and not accessible from my swift file.